# A puzzle that came when I am half awake

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

When I am about to wake up in the morning, a puzzle crept into my mind.It is

when $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ are both non-integers where $a,b$ are positive integers is it possible for $\sqrt{ab}$ to be an integer.

**My try:** ***Still in half wakeup***

If $\sqrt{ab}$ is an integer then $a + b + \sqrt{ab}$ is a positive integer

=> $(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})^2$ is a positive integer

But I was unable to move forward from here.

I tried for different combination but didn't found any such pair $a,b$.
Is one exits. How to find it or prove no such pair exist

**Edit:** I think for every case of $a=b$, this hold good, so I think that cases should be omitted

Comment: $a = b = 2 {}{}$.

Comment: Let $n^2 = k$ where $n \in \mathbb N $. Then, $a = \dfrac{k}{x}, b = x$, where $\sqrt{x} \not\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: That's possible even if $a$ and $b$ are negative: $a=b=-1$. Then $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ are not even real, let alone integers, but $\sqrt{ab}$ is an integer.

Comment: @TanmayInamdar so any perfect square which have factor other than its root satisfy this. Like for k=36, then a=12, b=3 but not for a=4,b=9. I think we have got a useful relation. But how can I get such square numbers.

Comment: @saikirangrandhi as you said, we require squares that have factors other than its root (and $1$, of course). Note that the factors of $p^2$ are $1, p, p^2$, where $p$ is a prime, the only case that does not satisfy the condition. Thus, any $q^2$ when $q$ is composite (note that this condition ensures $q \neq 1$) will work.

Comment: @TanmayInamdar I think you can write this as an answer so that I mark it as the correct one and close this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only divisors of $p^2$, where $p$ is prime, are $1, p, p^2$ and thus cannot be a solution.

Thus, choose square of any composite number $q$.

Since a composite number can be written as $q = \prod\limits_{p_i \text{prime}} p_i^{e_i}$ where $e_i \ge 0$ and there is at least one $e_i > 0$.

Suppose, for the sake of simplicity, $q = p_1p_2$. Then, $q^2 = p_1^2 p_2^2$. Now $q^2 = (p_1p_1p_2)(p_2)$ and neither of $p_1p_1p_2$ and $p_2$ are perfect squares.

Now, set $\sqrt{a} = \sqrt{p_1p_1p_2} = \sqrt{\dfrac{q^2}{p_2}}$ and $ \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{p_2} = \sqrt{\dfrac{q^2}{p_1p_1p_2}}$, both of which are not natural numbers, however their product $ = \sqrt{\dfrac{q^2}{p_1^2p_2^2}} = 1$ is a natural number.

This can be generalized in similar way for general $q = \prod\limits_{p_i \text{prime}} p_i^{e_i}$, and thus you have an infinite number of solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Just choose $a,b$ so that neither of them are square numbers but $ab$ is a square number.

Example: $a=3, b=12, \sqrt{ab}=6$

Comment: This is essentially just a restatement of the problem.

Comment: @Rahul no, OP asks how to find $a, b$.

Answer (score 0):

if you choose a,b such that gcd(a,b) = 1 it never happens..for any other case,given an a you can always find a "b" satisfying the condition.

Comment: Perhaps you can say more about choosing $b$ when $a$ is given?

Answer (score 0):

Let $v_p(n)$ be the exponent of the prime $p$ in the factorization of $n$.

Then, $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ are both non-integers and $\sqrt{ab}$ is an integer iff $v_p(a)$ and $v_p(b)$ have the same parity for all primes $p$.

In particular, given $a$, you can find $b$ by taking the product of all $p$ such that $v_p(a)$ is odd. You can find infinitely many $b$ by multiplying that product by a square.